# Unable to create a broadcast stream in flutter

Tags: flutter

Note: Please read edit first.

I want to create a broadcast stream for providing to Stream Builder. And I also have to attach websocket url to it. Using StreamController [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/StreamController-class.html), this is what i've implemented. I have read similar questions but couldn't figure out the problem.

```
final WebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://192.168.225.220:6969/test");


Class _Sample extends state<Sample>{
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mystream = channel.stream;
    controller = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
    controller.addStream(mystream);
    subscription = controller.stream.listen((data) => data, onDone: () => print("Task done") , onError: (error) => error);
  }

   ///widget tree
     child: StreamBuilder(
                            stream: mystream,                           
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError){
                                 return Text(snapshot.hasData.toString());
                              }
                              return Text("No Data");
                            }
                          ),
   ///widget tree
}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

EDIT: 
I realized after @andras pointed out I'm listening to the stream multiple times. I have read the documentation many times and viewed implementations for Stream and Streambuilder but still I am not able to comprehend Streams. For my implementation, I want to send data from a client to server. And multiple clients should be able to listen to this data.Hence, I want to create a broadcast stream so that multiple listeners can listen to a broadcasting client on a websocket channel.

So far this is what I have understood,
I create a websocket channel, this channel provides a single subscription [stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/web_socket_channel/latest/web_socket_channel/WebSocketChannel/stream.html) where I have provided a url for server communication.
`final WebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://192.168.225.220:6969/test");`

Now to create a broadcast stream there is a [StreamController.broadcast constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html) and to attach a source there is [addStream() method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/addStream.html)

```
void initState(){
   controller = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
   controller.addStream(channel.stream);
   subscription = controller.stream.listen((data) => data, onDone: () => print("Task done") , onError: (error) => error);
}
```

So I'm listening on controller.stream, now I want to attach this stream to Streambuilder so I can update builder whenever there is data from stream. 
I'm echoing the data to same client using

```
controller.sink.add(data)
```

Error i get when i try to use the stream.

```
The following StateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Bad state: Cannot add new events while doing an addStream
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The error description seems pretty detailed.

You listen to the stream once in the `initState` and then `StreamBuilder` does also listen to the stream you pass into it.

Think about your code a bit and see if [`broadcast`](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#broadcast-streams) methods fits for your use case if you want to stick to multiple listeners.

Comment: I have updated my post, can you please check. @andras

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says 'Events must not be added directly to this controller using `add`, `addError`, `close` or `addStream`, until the returned future is complete.'

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-async/StreamController/addStream.html

I think you should use `listen` to web sockets stream and `add` events manually instead of using `addStream()`